# Viewing visual Signature in iOS-App

Tags: ios, objective-c, pdf, signature, uidocumentinteraction

I'm using the `UIDocumentInteractioncontroller` for displaying pdfs and images in my application. If i try to display a `pdf` with a visual signature, the signature is not shown.

On the other hand, if I use the native mail app to preview the same `pdf`, the visual signature is shown.

Am I missing some configuration or is the native app using a different `DocumentController`?

Here's my code:

```
UIDocumentInteractionController *documentInteractionController =[UIDocumentInteractionController interactionControllerWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:navigatorImpl.fileUrl]];
    documentInteractionController.delegate = self;
    [documentInteractionController presentPreviewAnimated:YES];
```

Thanks in advance!

Herbert